# Fastest way to get map object to list

Tags: python, function, csv, dictionary, mapping

I have a function that processes text files. I have a list of approximately 73K files that I want to run through this function. The function returns a list of dictionaries, each representing one row in my output. After I process all them, I write the results to a csv using csv.DictWriter.

What I have been doing so far is `results = [i for sublist in [*map(lambda f: process_func(f), files] for i in sublist]` or `list(map(process_func, files))`. Each of these takes about 3.5 minutes. When I just do something like `map(process_func, files)`, it takes about 350 ms.

I need to scale this up and the process of turning the map object into a list essentially takes all of the time the script needs to run. Is there a more efficient way to this?

Comment: I don't think you'll get anything faster than `list(your_iterator)`, but, depending on what `process func` and `files` are, maybe a numpy solution would be faster?

Comment: process_fun essentially parses the file by removing everything I don't need and then uses spacy's phase matcher to match patterns within the file.

Comment: Right, it's hard to say whether a numpy solution would work without seeing the whole thing.

Comment: Perhaps, what needs clarification is that the map function is lazy, which is why it is so quick. It is just returning a generator to be computed later, but when you cast it to a list, only then are you actually running your function. That's why it takes much longer, not because it takes long to convert generators to lists, but because that's actually where the computations happen. So, to make it faster, you'll have to look at working on your function, not so much the very fast _C-implemented_ `list` function.

Comment: Thanks. Just in general, what do you mean by numpy solution?

Comment: [The numpy library for scientific computing in python](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/)

Comment: FYI, `lambda f: process_func(f)` can be written just `process_func`.